# Can I chain a js function to a reference of an element object?

Tags: javascript

So quick example

```
//example
var el = document.getElementById("test");
el.classList.add("my-class");

//my function
var myFunction = function(){//code goes here};
el.myFunction();

//and can we take it further by adding a method to it like classList does
el.myFunction().myMethod();
```

I know I'm probably not using the right lingo here, because a method is a function of a class which means `myFunction()` must be a class. I'm just confused on if something like this is possible. Anyways...

**How can i create a function that can be chained to an element like that?**

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-like-boss-understanding-fluent-apis/

Comment: this line `el.myFunction();` will already throw an exception

Comment: If you're looking for the right lingo, search for "How do I add methods to DOM elements". You'd have to add the methods `myFunction` and `myMethod` to the class of `el`.

Comment: For chaining, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=method+chaining+[js]). Notice that a better approach would be `myFunction(el).myMethod().myMethod()`

Comment: I know libraries that do what you want, but instead I'd recommend looking in functional programming and function currying.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I didn't know the lingo to search for this stuff. I'll check it out